# Pyspark freezing after an operation on aggregated Data Frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.5.2 with Python 2.7.5.

I have this code that I run in the pyspark repl:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
ctx = SQLContext(sc)

df = ctx.createDataFrame([("a",1),("a",1),("a",0),("a",0),("b",1),("b",0),("b",1)],["group","conversion"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, avg
funs = [(count,"total"),(avg,"cr")]
aggregate = ["conversion"]
exprs = [f(col(c)).alias(name) for f,name in funs for c in aggregate]
df3 = df.groupBy("group").agg(*exprs).cache()
```

So far the code works fine and I can check `df3`:

```
>>> df3.collect()
[Row(group=u'a', total=4, cr=0.5), Row(group=u'b', total=3, cr=0.6666666666666666)]
```

However, when I try:

```
df3.agg(sum(col('cr'))).first()[0]
```

PySpark can't calculate that sum. However `df3.rdd.reduce(lambda x,y: x[2]+y[2])` works just fine.

So, what is the issue with the first command to calculate the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import pyspark's `sum` function first: `from pyspark.sql.functions import sum`. Otherwise python's built-in `sum` is called which just sums the sequence of numbers.

Comment: Indeed, it works when importing `sum`, thanks. One thing, though, the data frame I was trying to sum had only two rows, and I was running pyspark locally (not in distributed mode). Do you know why the built-in `sum` function was slow, given that?

Comment: Built-it `sum` will not work. Spark was probably retrying aggregations stage (failing each time) and this could last long time.